# Reverse of a string using pointers without using string handling functions?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I have updated the code as per the comments. As I am not near a PC, could you please check it and update me on that?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char s[100],rev[100],*ps1,*ps2,temp,*ptemp=&temp;
    int i,n=0;
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%s",s);
    printf("The string is: %s\n",s);
    for(i=0;s[i]!='\0';i++)
    n++;
    ps1=&s[0];
    ps2=&s[n-1];
    for(i=0;i<n/2;i++)
    {
        *ptemp=*ps1;
        *ps1=*ps2;
        *ps2=*ptemp;
        *ps2--;
        *ps1++;
    }
    printf("The reverse of the string is: %s\n",s);
}
```

Comment: I would start again - you have made this so complex - first error is ` scanf("%s", &s1);` as this should be ` scanf("%s", s1);`

Comment: I'm sure you had a reason for declaring `i` as `int*`. I just can't think of what that reason would be. The initializer statement in your `for` loop invokes *undefined behavior*. Same problem is repeated for `length`.

Comment: The second problem is dereferencing `i` before setting it to something.  It looks like you're in way over your head.  But luckily, C gives you more than enough rope to shoot yourself in the foot.  Good luck

Comment: How do you shoot yourself with rope? I would love to see that experiment.

Comment: @Ed Heal It's C.  The result of the autopsy is "drowning"

Comment: @EdHeal that's the beauty of UB, you can shoot yourself with *anything* (and sometimes, *nothing*).

Comment: @WhozCraig What's the problem if I use a pointer in a for loop?

Comment: @SriTejaChilakapati Ask yourself what it is *pointing **to*** ? If your answer is "I have no clue", then you're in good company, because neither does your program. I don't know what toolchain you're using, but I strongly suggest you investigate how to turn up its warning-levels to pedantic settings, then read, investigate, understand, and finally fix *everything* that is caught.

Comment: @SriTejaChilakapati: Do you known and understand what pointers are and how they work? You should read about that before attempting to write this code, or even worse, to give it to us to fix it.

Comment: @Ed Heal Both should be the same right?? In strings &s and s should be the same as it worked for me in other programs.

Comment: I would throw away this code. I would go and read up about pointers and arrays with desert being the manual page for `scanf`

Comment: @SriTejaChilakapati: ... You should read about *undefined behaviour*. Because something *seems* to work (and sometimes does) doesn't mean that the program is well-formed. Anything can happen later on if you do things wrong, and that's just what you've experienced.

Comment: @Tibrogargan - Where did the water come into it?

Comment: @SriTejaChilakapati Believe me, That is *not* what was intended when you were tasked with "using pointers" to reverse a string. They want you to position two `char *` at either end of the string, then start walking them toward each other (one forward, one backward), swapping characters along the way, until they either meet, or pass each other somewhere in the middle.

Comment: @Ed Heal http://www.amazon.com/Enough-Rope-Shoot-Yourself-Foot/dp/0070296898

Comment: @Tibrogargan *Outstanding*. I'll see that chuckle and raise you the library additions from [**O RLY**](https://imgur.com/gallery/vqUQ5). =P

Comment: @WhozCraig - The cat looks very angry. Is the Gorilla constipated?

Comment: @EdHeal Good question. Dunno, but if they could have picked a better image for Taking On Needless Dependencies, I don't see how.

Comment: @WhozCraig Well then... I have been taught wrong all this semester by my teacher then.. Thank god I came to know about it before my final exams!

Comment: What class are you taking? Obfuscrustaceaned code 101?

Comment: @SriTejaChilakapati Not gonna sugarcoat it; if I coded like that, on the "expert" guidance of a teacher for a semester, I'd probably sue for my tuition back.

Comment: @WhozCraig don't bag on my man Allen Holub, that's a real book :)

Comment: @Tibrogargan I am in my engineering second semester.

Comment: I have updated the code as per the comments. As I am not near a PC, could you please check it and update me on that?

Comment: You think that SO contributors are a free test and validation sevice?  FFS get yourself near a PC.

Comment: Also, if you are going to hack your code about while a question is live, you should apend new/changed code, not replace what was there originally, else you risk invalidating existing answers.

Comment: Do you understand that debugger programs exists, eg. gdb?

Answer (score 1):

Trying to keep code the closer to yours and making it works:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char s1[100], rev[100], *ps1=s1, *prev=rev;
    int value1, value2 = 0;
    int *i = &value1, *length = &value2; // Why the hell do you need pointers? But if you do want them, use them the right way
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%99s", s1); // parameter must be a 'char *', not a 'char **'
    printf("The string is: %s\n",s1); // Ends line with \n

    for(*i=0;*(ps1+(*i))!='\0';(*i)++)
    {
        (*length)++;
    }
    printf("The length is: %d\n", *length);

    for(*i=1;*(ps1+(*i)-1)!='\0';(*i)++)
    {
        *(prev+(*i)-1)=*(ps1+(*length)-(*i));
    }

    *(rev+(*i)-1)='\0';
    printf("\nThe reverse string is: %s\n",rev); // Ends line with \n
}
```

But I must confess your last loop is really hard to understand. Also, why do you need those pointers?

Edit: Also you should check return value of `scanf()` is 1. Because if is is not, it means `scanf()` did not set a value to `s1`.

Edit 2: Correction of the new version of the question

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char s[100],*ps1,*ps2,temp,*ptemp=&temp; // removing unused rev
    int i,n=0;
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%s",s);
    printf("The string is: %s\n",s);
    for(i=0;s[i]!='\0';i++)
    n++;
    ps1=&s[0]; // ps1 = s; would be fine
    ps2=&s[n-1]; // ps2 = s + (n-1); would be fine
    for(i=0;i<n/2;i++)
    {
        *ptemp=*ps1;
        *ps1=*ps2;
        *ps2=*ptemp;
        ps2--; // You want ps2 point to previous character
        ps1++; // You want ps1 point to next character
    }
    printf("The reverse of the string is: %s\n",s);
}
```

Comment: Yeah.. I got it down working. But as some others have mentioned, this is not the way to reverse a string using pointers. So, I updated the code. Could you take a look at that?

Comment: @Sri Teja Chilakapati First thing: you should not edit your question in a way it makes all answers and comments outdated. Second thing: You should compile your code with gcc options `-Wall -Wextra`. This is what I did and I got warnings telling me you never use `rev`, and you never use some values affected to `ps2`.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem I see is that scanf expects a pointer, but you give it a pointer to a memory address which is effectively a pointer to pointer:

```
scanf("%s", &s1);
```

Should be changed to:

```
char s1[100] = {0};
scanf("%s", s1);
```

---

As scanf does not check for memory overflow, it would be a wiser choice to make use of this syntax over the above suggested one

```
char s1[100] = {0};
scanf("%99s", s1);
```

This way, you don't get into any buffer overflow issues

---

Next problem, you dereference a pointer before assigning it a valid location in memory:

```
for(*i=0;*(ps1+(*i))!='\0';(*i)++)
```

Change to:

```
int i;
for(i = 0; ps1[i] != '\0'; i++)
```

Do the same for your other for-loop

Finally, remove this line:

```
*(rev+(*i)-1)='\0';
```

And change the print statement to:

```
printf("\nThe reverse string is: %s",s1);
```

Comment: Perhaps using `scanf("%99s", s1)` would be better

Comment: `*(ps1 + i) ` -> `ps1[i]` is a bit more readable

Comment: @Smax89 oh dear, why use `int i; for(i = 0;` when you could use `long double *unused; for(*(i = (int*)&unused)=0;`???

Comment: @Tibrogargan I forgot to bring enough rope to shoot myself in the head. Sorry next time I will make sure to include that